# what is wrong with the code of the figure?

Tags: documentation

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=10mm]{penduloPlano.png}
\caption{Rota\c{c}\~{a}o do suporte ocorrendo a manuten\c{c}\~{a}o do plano de oscila\c{c}\~{a}o do p\^{e}ndulo.}
\label{fig:rota\c{c}\~{a}o do p\^{e}ndulo}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I have the image in the same folder that the tex file.

Comment: You need `\usepackage{float}` to use `[H]`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I make that, but gave me error too. The error is: `! Missing \endcsname inserted.`

Comment: I noticed there is almost no response to answers that address your questions. None of the is marked as *the answer solved my problem*.

Answer (score 2):

Three things are wrong:

1. You need `\usepackage{float}` to use `[H]`.
2. You need `\usepackage{graphicx}` to use `\includegraphics`.
3. You can't have (and don't want) the accents in the `label`, use something like `\label{fig:rotacaopendulo}` instead.

---

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{float,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=10mm]{example-image}
\caption{Rota\c{c}\~{a}o do suporte ocorrendo a manuten\c{c}\~{a}o do plano de oscila\c{c}\~{a}o do p\^{e}ndulo.}
\label{fig:rotacaopendulo}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```